# ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib64/libthread.so.1' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored

Tags: server, 20.04, ld

I have multiple Ubuntu & Debian servers & today all of them started outputting the following message when running commands on the shell:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib64/libthread.so.1' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Debian is off topic here.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 & Debian 10

Comment: AFAIK `/etc/ld.so.preload` is not a "normal" thing to exist - in fact, the ld.so.conf manpage says it "is typically employed only as an emergency remedy, for example,  as a temporary workaround to a library misconfiguration issue". Also I can't find `/usr/lib64/libthread.so.1` in any standard Ubuntu package (Linux uses pthreads I think?). So it sounds like something you have configured yourself (perhaps to support some non-native application?)